# Module imported before executing a function but got a reference error in the function

Tags: python-3.x

```
def func_a():
    try:
        print(os.name)
    except Exception as e:
        import os
        print(e)
        print(os.name)
        
import os
print(os.name)
func_a()


def func_b():
    try:
        print(os.name)
    except Exception as e:
        # import os
        print(e)
        print(os.name)
        
import os
print(os.name)
func_b()
```

These are the outputs:

> nt
>
> local variable 'os' referenced before assignment
>
> nt
>
> nt
>
> nt

I expect the output of 2nd row to be nt, but got a reference error instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code will try to help you understand the situation better.

```
a = 10

print(a)
def func():
  try:
    print(a)
  except Exception as e:
    a =  'str'
    print(e)
    print(a)

func()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
10
local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
str
10
```

Global variables are the one that is defined and declared outside a function and we need to use them inside a function.

If a variable with the same name is defined inside the scope of function as well then it will print the value given inside the function only and not the global value.

Now let us take the example of your code described in the question.

`import os` is an assignment to the os variable name in the function but it is used in the before its assignment.

I think @user2357112 tried to explain the same thing. I just added an example to help you better understand.

For more details, you can check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Hoping, this answer will help.

Comment: @QZQ Happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

The way you tried to recover from `os` being missing is, in fact, what is causing `os` to be missing.

The existence of an assignment to a variable name in a function causes that function to have a local variable with that name, shadowing any global or builtin by that name, unless this behavior is explicitly overridden by a `global` or `nonlocal` statement. `import os` *is an assignment* to the `os` variable name, causing `func_a` to have a local `os` variable. This local is unassigned when `func_a` tries to `print(os.name)`, causing the `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your anwser. but `os` has been imported before `fun_a`, why the `import os` after `except` affects the `import os` before `fun_a`?